# How to extract values with the same key from array and compute their average?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, key

so I have a few arrays for different datasets that look similair to this one:

```
[["zufrieden",10],
["beschämt",24],
["gelangweilt",50],
["begeistert",28],
["unsicher",27],
["niedergeschlagen",49],
["verärgert",72],
["frustriert",29], 
["entspannt",25],
["unsicher",27],
["unsicher",31],
["schuldig",22],
["frustriert",18], 
["gelangweilt",73],
["wütend",30],
["verlegen",50],
["besorgt",25],
["schwermütig",0]]
```

How can i get, for example, the average value of all entries with "schuldig".
Also, I need to do this for every single key that is represented by a string in this case. 
I tried converting the array to an object and go from there, but I'm stuck and would appreciate any help.

I already came as far counting the occurences of the different strings using the map function.

```
var counts = {};
orderedFeelings.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
var countsValues = Object.keys(counts).map(function(key){ return counts[key] });
```

This is okay for my intent to visualize the data as it returns a list of the occurences, but in order to create a detailed graph, I need to have the average value of all values with the same keys. This is where I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Please post the code that is trying to achieve this... and point out errors/issues.. plus SO is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information in one object, with just one iteration O(n):

```js
var arr = [
  ["zufrieden", 10],
  ["beschämt", 24],
  ["gelangweilt", 50],
  ["begeistert", 28],
  ["unsicher", 27],
  ["niedergeschlagen", 49],
  ["verärgert", 72],
  ["frustriert", 29],
  ["entspannt", 25],
  ["unsicher", 27],
  ["unsicher", 31],
  ["schuldig", 22],
  ["frustriert", 18],
  ["gelangweilt", 73],
  ["wütend", 30],
  ["verlegen", 50],
  ["besorgt", 25],
  ["schwermütig", 0]
]


var average = {}

arr.map(o => {
  if (o[0] in average) {
    average[o[0]][0] += o[1]
    average[o[0]][1]++
      average[o[0]][2] = average[o[0]][0] / average[o[0]][1]
  } else {
    average[o[0]] = []
    average[o[0]].push(o[1]);//<-- Name
    average[o[0]].push(1);//<-- Quantity
    average[o[0]].push(o[1] / 1);//<-- Average
  }
})

console.log(average.schuldig[2])//<-- Average
console.log(average)
```

The key is always calculate the average, at the end, we have the real average.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to get there.

Comment: Your welcome @Sky , accept the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` method of array

```
const newArray = this.array.filter(temp => temp[0] === 'schuldig');
var total = 0;
for (each of newArray) {
  total += each[1];
}
const avg = (total/newArray.length);
```

This will give you average the wayx you need  it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predefined format of your dataset like at the first index of each array will be the text and at the second index of array will be the value then you can compute the average by this

```
function computeAvg(dataset,key) {
  let desiredElements = dataset.filter(item => item[0] === key);
  return (desiredElements.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current[1],0))/desiredElements.length; 
}

let dataset = [["zufrieden",10],
["beschämt",24],
["gelangweilt",50],
["begeistert",28],
["unsicher",27],
["niedergeschlagen",49],
["verärgert",72],
["frustriert",29], 
["entspannt",25],
["unsicher",27],
["unsicher",31],
["schuldig",22],
["frustriert",18], 
["gelangweilt",73],
["wütend",30],
["verlegen",50],
["besorgt",25],
["schwermütig",0]]; 

let average = computeAvg(dataset,'schuldig');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group all the entries by key with `Array.prototype.reduce` while counting total sum and their amount, and then go through grouped object and calculate averages:

```js
var data=[["zufrieden",10],["beschämt",24],["gelangweilt",50],["begeistert",28],["unsicher",27],["niedergeschlagen",49],["verärgert",72],["frustriert",29],["entspannt",25],["unsicher",27],["unsicher",31],["schuldig",22],["frustriert",18],["gelangweilt",73],["wütend",30],["verlegen",50],["besorgt",25],["schwermütig",0]];

var grouped = data.reduce((all, [key, val]) => {

    if (!all[key]) all[key] = {sum: 0, count:0}

    all[key].count++;
    all[key].sum += val;

    return all;

},{});

var averages = Object.keys(grouped).reduce((all, k) => {

    all[k] = parseInt(grouped[k].sum / grouped[k].count);

    return all;

}, {});

console.log(averages.zufrieden);
console.log(averages.unsicher);
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through your data, use array's filter function and compare your current object's [0] index with filters object's [0] index. Now you have matched elements, now use array's reduce method to calculate sum for current key i.e 'zufrieden' and then divide its value by the length of matched array and push that value in current iteration of outer loop i.e 'x'

```js
const data = [
  ["zufrieden", 10],
  ["beschämt", 24],
  ["gelangweilt", 50],
  ["begeistert", 28],
  ["unsicher", 27],
  ["niedergeschlagen", 49],
  ["verärgert", 72],
  ["frustriert", 29],
  ["entspannt", 25],
  ["unsicher", 27],
  ["unsicher", 31],
  ["schuldig", 22],
  ["frustriert", 18],
  ["gelangweilt", 73],
  ["wütend", 30],
  ["verlegen", 50],
  ["besorgt", 25],
  ["schwermütig", 0]
];

/* 
loop through your data, use array's filter function and compare your current object's [0] index with filters object's [0] index. Now you have matched elements, now use array's reduce method to calculate sum for current key i.e 'zufrieden' and then divide its value by the length of matched array and push that value in current iteration of outer loop i.e 'x'
*/

data.forEach(x => {
  const matched = data.filter(y => y[0] == x[0]);
  x.push(matched.map(z => z[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / matched.length);
});

console.log(data);
```